# Spring RabbitMq - Apply custom payload converter

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

How do I apply a custom `payloadConverter` in `MessagingMessageConverter`. It defaults to the `SimpleMessageConverter` class.

I can easily apply a `messageConverter` onto the `rabbitTemplate`, but it only affects the outgoing message.

The `MessagingMessageConverter` belongs to the `MessagingMessageListenerAdapter`.

Do I need to create a `containerFactory` in order to apply a `payloadConverter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you set the converter on the container factory; you can either define your own bean or modify the one created by Boot. I assume you are using boot because otherwise you would have already had to define a factory.

```java
@Component
class ContainerCustomizer {

    public ContainerCustomizer(AbstractRabbitListenerContainerFactory<?> factory) {
        factory.setMessageConverter(...);
    }

}
```